# WinApi c++ window won't appear oop

Tags: windows, oop, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to create a demo where the window frame is handled in it's own class and called in the WinMain file, I have the main.cpp and window.h and window.cpp,the code compiles successfully but the window will not show up despite popping up in the system tray with the window title I passed in main.cpp, here is the entire code:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "window.h"


window* WinapiInit = new window;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE PrevhInstance, LPSTR 
lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
WinapiInit->initWindow(hInstance, 800, 600, L"DirectX 12 Demo", nCmdShow);

delete WinapiInit;

return 0;
}
```

**window.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

class window
{

private:
LPCWSTR m_WindowTitle;
const LPCTSTR m_WindowClassName = L"WindowClass1";

int m_WindowWidth;
int m_WindowHeight;
const int m_ScreenPosX = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
const int m_ScreenPosY = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);


HWND hWnd;
WNDCLASSEX wcex;
MSG msg;

public:
void initWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, int WindowWidth, int WindowHeight, 
LPCWSTR WindowTitle, int nCmdShow);
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM 
lParam);
void mainLoop();

};
```

**window.cpp**

```
#include "window.h"


LRESULT window::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (uMsg)
{
 case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    ExitProcess(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    break;
}
return 0;
}

void window::mainLoop()
{
msg = { 0 };
while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    //GAME CODE HERE
    //...

}
}

void window::initWindow(const HINSTANCE hInstance,  int WindowWidth,  int 
WindowHeight, LPCWSTR WindowTitle, const int nCmdShow)
{

m_WindowWidth = WindowWidth;
m_WindowHeight = WindowHeight;
m_WindowTitle = WindowTitle;

wcex = { 0 };
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 3);
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = window::WndProc;
wcex.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
wcex.lpszClassName = m_WindowClassName;
wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"RegisterClassEx Call Error!", L"ERROR" , MB_OK | 
    MB_ICONERROR);
}

hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, m_WindowClassName, WindowTitle,
                      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, m_ScreenPosX, m_ScreenPosY, 
WindowWidth,
                      WindowHeight, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

if (!hWnd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"CreateWindowEx Call Error!", L"ERROR", MB_OK | 
    MB_ICONERROR);
}

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

mainLoop();

}
```

What exactly causes the window not to show up? I am a beginner in object oriented programming so that's where I think the issue is but I can't figure it out, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Dan ok then, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Cody Gray well, WinapiInit is a pointer to the window class(hopefully) which I posted the header and cpp file for, any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Dan: If you're doing to do Win32 development with MFC, you might take a look at Qt.

Comment: @sergiol Could you help me out with this code?

Comment: I am not an expert on [winapi] as you can see in my profile.

Comment: Please leave @Raymond's title edit alone, it is correct. We do not add title hacks here, since we have a fully-fledged acceptance system. If you see someone with high rep, it is probably worth considering they have a good idea of how Stack Overflow works, so please ping them using their `@handle` before entering into an edit war. Thanks.

Comment: @halfer No edit war here, I just didn't realise someone had a problem with my title, speaking of which, what is the problem with adding [SOLVED]??

Comment: Happy to answer that. The [solved] title hack was popularised by Q&A sites running forum software that has no specific system for marking a best answer. That is still very common even to this day, and it is considered a mark of netiquette to help identify posts in this fashion. However, the Stack Exchange sites featured a built-in acceptance and voting system, and by using that, posts can be identified as solved (or not) using filters, searches, or the API. Questions marked correctly as solved are coloured differently in question lists too.

Comment: Since we have such a system, using the title to mark a question as solved is a bit redundant, as well as untidy. Thus, for uniformity of presentation, we remove [solved] devices. Such edits can be very useful to discover when someone has edited their answer into their question as an addendum, and we don't do that either. They are either rolled back by editors, or we try to ask posters to make that edit themselves. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of things that are wrong here because you have managed to make a simple application very complicated, and hence hard to debug,

Most critically with regards to your problem, you initialize m_ScreenPosX and m_ScreenPosY with the System Metrics SM_CXSCREEN and SM_CYSCREEN - which by definition means the window has been positioned outside the visible area of the desktop.

As this looks like it is supposed to grow into a DirectX app, you probably want to use 0,0 as the position, and the dimensions of the primary display (which, on a multi display system is going to NOT be SM_CXSCREEN, SM_CYSCREEN) to position the window on the primary display.

But in the short term, CW_USEDEFAULT would be a sensible position value to use for initial development.

The next most critical source of errors is your inclusion of the message loop as part of your window class. Most - if not all - OOP frameworks for windows development separate "window" from "application", even if there is only a single application window. This means the application object owns the message loop, and it NEVER filters by hWnd: Messages posted to the application (such as WM_QUIT) are not sent to an HWND, which (presumably) is why your WM_DESTROY handler also calls ExitProcess. Remove the call to ExitProcess, and remove the hWnd filtering, and PostQuitMessage() will cause your app to terminate cleanly.

Lastly, unless you just want to store a singleton of your window class (as the game window its unlikely this would cause problems really) you are going to quickly chafe at having to implement your entire window class as static methods.
The usual method is to use `SetWindowLongPtr/GetWindowLongPtr` with `GWLP_USERDATA` to store, and retrieve, your `this` pointer in your static WndProc so it can call non-static class methods.